# Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth)

Tags: linkedin-api

i would like implement OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow (2-Legged), but as mentioned here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow  or  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow.

It's written : "Your application cannot access these APIs by default. Contact us to have your application granted permission to use this flow."

I don't find any contact (I tried linkedin support, they sent me on stack overflow..), does anyone has already done this setup ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar boat and it seems that you will have to apply for further permissions on their partner programme page: https://developer.linkedin.com/content/developer/global/en_us/index/partner-programs/apply

I know this may be a bit of a late response but other developers stumbling across this may benefit from this answer.

Comment: did you have any luck getting 2-legged OAuth authentication work for LinkedIn?
I have added all the products that I could for my app in the dashboard and I am still unable to get an application token to access any of the standards APIs such as skills API

Comment: Unfortunately, that link now 404's